# Separate tag for [set-returning-functions]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I noticed that [set-returning-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-returning-functions) has been made a synonym of [functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions). (*Paul White♦, Sep 29 at 13:33*, if I read https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms correctly.

I am not too happy with this, since functions returning a *set* exhibit a family of problems distinct from plain functions and I would like to be able to search for *that*.

[table-valued-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-functions) (currently also synonym of [functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions)) and [table-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-functions) (not there yet) could be synonyms of [set-returning-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-returning-functions).

Do you agree?
If so, can the change be reverted? Or are original tags lost after the merge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok:

- [set-returning-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-returning-functions) is no longer a synonym of [functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions).
- [table-valued-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-functions) is no longer a synonym of [functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions)
- [table-valued-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-functions) is now a synonym of [set-returning-functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-returning-functions) as requested.

No tag assignments were lost.

We can monitor the usage of these tags and revisit the situation after a period of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your swift action!

Answer (score 2):

While I don't love it either, I do think that the `functions` tag works *best* as a broad tag.

As Evan alluded to, there are a ton of more specific versions (far more than the 4 listed) that *could* exist, but I think that it would be more confusing than helpful for many askers and most of them wouldn't get a lot of use.

So, I propose an alternative: `built-in-function` to refer to out of the box functions and `user-defined-function` to refer to custom functions. These would provide more clarity without resulting in too many permutations of `function` tag options. This would help categorize the general problem area of the question - how to use the DB feature functions properly/efficiently vs. custom coding help/errors.

It would be good, of course, to also tag the language in this scenario as well (and I guess any scenario).

Comment: I can't see `user-defined`  as being useful, if it's user-defined you should just tag the language you're using to define it. (Just me though). Also, builtins change quite frequently (moving from non-builtins to builtins). Seems a bit problematic too.

Comment: @LowlyDBA I tend to agree that [tag:functions] works best, but we'll see how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

The function tag should be dissolved for being too broad. There are 10,000 ways to slice up. You've made an argument for one of them, I like it. My preference would be to ban the tag entirely and go with something like,

- Window functions       `functions-window`
- Aggregate functions    `functions-aggregate`
- Table-Value Functions  `functions-table-valued`
- Scalar-Value Functions `functions-scalar-valued`

This defines the role of the function, and all tags should carry a mention to **also tag** the language you're using if you're writing a function, (`tsql`, `c-sharp`, `perl`, `plpgsql`) etc.

Generally, I like the PostgreSQL naming conventions and they're close to the spec. But the spec doesn't provide guidance for a break down. The terms `scalar` and `table` are used in Microsoft and IBM. "Scalar" is used in [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)) and [most every computer language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science))

Why not `Set-returning`?

I don't know of anything else where we call something that can act as a table a "set", and it seems very likely to be confusing if actual SQL multisets are ever introduced in Pg, or in any db that has them.